# Spring OAuth2 refresh token to change after refreshing access token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I created an authentication server and resource server, both are working ok, the only problem is with refresh token, I would like it to change after calling `POST /oauth/token` with `grant_type=refresh_token`, however, spring returns same refresh token.

I am wondering if there is a way to get a new refresh token when calling oauth endpoint to refresh access token?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By taking a look at [`refreshAccessToken`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java#L171) method in the `DefaultTokenServices` class:

```
public OAuth2AccessToken refreshAccessToken(String refreshTokenValue, 
                                            TokenRequest tokenRequest) {

    // Omitted
    if (!reuseRefreshToken) {
        tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        refreshToken = createRefreshToken(authentication);
    }
    // Omitted
}
```

You should somehow set the `reuseRefreshToken` flag to `false`. You can do that in your `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // Other methods

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }
}
```