# What to do when the azure ad token expires?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I generated an application with jhipster and perform all the settings of the lib **com.microsoft.azure.**

The login is working perfectly, my question is how can I handle when the azure AD token expires (it is set to expire in 1 hour).

Can I do this using a filter in SecurityConfiguration?

```
   @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
            .and()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
        .frameOptions()
        .deny()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService());
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options when token expires: one is renewing the token with [refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-tokens), another is requesting the `/token` endpoint again to get the new one.

Try to follow this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java

If the access token is expired, it will call `refreshAccessToken()` function. And there is a similar issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882576/13308381).